# PyQt - How to open a directory folder?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have searched a lot and I know how to open a directory dialog window. 
But what I am looking for is the method to open a directory folder under windows OS, just like you right click one of your local folder and select open.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

For python 3.7 you can just do:

```
os.startfile(path)
```

Comment: This is much much older than Python 3.7: [python docs indicates addition in Python 2.0!](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/os.html#os.startfile).

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
dir_ = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select a folder:', 'C:\\', QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
```

If the user hits cancel, then dir_ is empty.

Comment: Thanks...but you didn't understand my question. These codes open a dialog window for user to choose a dir. However, what I need is just open a system folder under window 7.

Answer (score 5):

To open the folder in a file explorer you can just do this:

```
import webbrowser


webbrowser.open("path\to\the\file")
```

This works on any platf

Comment: Worked for me, but had to make sure that the directories existed.

Answer (score 4):

You may simply try this:

`os.startfile(whatever_valid_filename)`

This starts the default OS application for `whatever_valid_filename`, meaning Explorer for a folder name, default notepad for a `.txt` file, etc.

Answer (score 4):

For the effect that you are looking for do this :

```
import os
os.system('explorer.exe "C:\users\%username%\Desktop"')
```

This opens your Desktop window just like you open any folder. You can substitute `C:\users\%username%\Desktop` with whatever folder you need to open.

Answer (score 3):

the answers here are for PyQt4.

So if you try these solutions you will get an error

So to deal with it, here  I have the solution for PyQt5

```
dir_ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select project folder:', 'F:\\', QtWidgets.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly)
```

And you are done.

Thank me later!