# Using simple PyQT UI to choose directory path crushing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am kind of new to Python and especially new to PyQT.
I Used PyQT5 to create a very simple gui. Now, I would like to upgrade it to involve something more real then to calculate number operations.

I want a user to choose a directory with images.
After that and some other small operations like ticking some check boxes I want to run an algorithm of mine in the background and in the mean while to show him/her the progress via a progressBar.

This is my code right now:

```
import sys
from os.path import expanduser

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5 import uic, QtGui

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("mainGui_3A.ui")


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton_Directory.clicked.connect(self.choose_directory)
        self.ui.pushButton_CreateAlbum.clicked.connect(self.create_album)

    def choose_directory(self):
        my_dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
        self,
        "Open a folder",
        expanduser("~"),
        QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
    )
        self.ui.lineEdit_Directory.setText(my_dir)

    def create_album(self):
        current_dir = self.ui.lineEdit_Directory.toPlainText()
        check1 = self.ui.checkBox_1.value()
        check2 = self.ui.checkBox_2.value()
        return current_dir, check1, check2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have looked at :

[PYQT - How to open a directory folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23859613/pyqt-how-to-open-a-directory-folder)

[PyQt: QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory using a default directory, user independant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24739533/pyqt-qfiledialog-getexistingdirectory-using-a-default-directory-user-independa)

as you can see I still didn't add the last bit since the error below but I think I need to look into:

[Example of the right way to use QThread in PyQt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879971/example-of-the-right-way-to-use-qthread-in-pyqt)

[Change the value of the progress bar from a class other than my GUI class PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415737/change-the-value-of-the-progress-bar-from-a-class-other-than-my-gui-class-pyqt4)

There is no error at first. the ui is loaded currectly I believe but as soon as I click one of my buttons the program stop running.. what did I do wrong? do I need to use threads to choose the directory?

Any tips for the future would be welcomed!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does it mean it stops running? It exists? I dont see anything obviously wrong except (i hope) invalid formatting - create_album should be a method of class MyApp, right?

Comment: when I click any of the buttons I get the known message that it's title is 'Python has stopped working' (from Windows) and then I am advise to close the program... this does bot happen when I click the checkBox. you are right and the create_album is a method in the class - formatting error.

Comment: corrected formatting problem mentioned above

Comment: I would advise against using threads - certainly not necessary for picking a directory - and, while very powerful, a steep learning curve. Are you running the program from a command prompt? Or an IDE? Are there any exception messages?

Comment: not from the cmd but via IDE (PyCharm)... no exceptions all I get is: 'Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't like the idea of answering my own questions but I guess that if this could save someone several hours of research that its quite alright.

so here it is I found a solution and the possible error in my code.

***Solution:***

```
import sys
from os.path import expanduser

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import uic, QtGui, QtCore

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType("mainGui_3A.ui")


class MyApp(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        logo_src = "appLogo.png"
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(logo_src))
        self.ui.pushButton_Directory.clicked.connect(self.choose_directory)
        self.ui.pushButton_CreateAlbum.clicked.connect(self.create_album)
        self.ui.pushButton_Directory.setToolTip('Choose directory')
        self.ui.checkBox_Quality.setToolTip('Include image quality assessment upon selection of representative photos')
        self.ui.checkBox_Launch.setToolTip('Display output album when done')

    def choose_directory(self):
        print("Hello1")
        input_dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select a folder:', expanduser("~"))
        self.ui.lineEdit_Directory.setText(input_dir)




    def create_album(self):
        print("Hello2")
        current_dir = self.ui.lineEdit_Directory.text()
        if current_dir != "":
            quality = self.ui.checkBox_Quality.isChecked()
            launch = self.ui.checkBox_Launch.isChecked()
            print(current_dir)
            print(quality)
            print(launch)
        return 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**possible error I found via text comparison:**

- Using

  ```
  my_dir = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
      self,
      "Open a folder",
      expanduser("~"),
      QtGui.QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
  )
  ```

instead of

```
    input_dir = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(None, 'Select a folder:', 
        expanduser("~"))
```